# observing script execution with monit script seems to ignore pipes

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe

I want to have a bash command running in the background and being watched by monit.
To get the PID of this process, I found this script on the web and I modified it to fit my commands: (named sdr.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="sdr"
LOG_FILE="/tmp/$NAME.log"
PID_FILE="/var/run/$NAME.pid"
CMD="/usr/local/bin/rtl_fm -o 4 -A lut -s 22050 -f 254.2355M - | /usr/local/bin/multimon-ng -t raw -f alpha /dev/stdin |& /home/me/import.rb"

function startnotification {
VAR=`ps -ef | grep "$CMD" | grep -v grep | wc -l`
if [ $VAR -gt 0 ]; then
echo "$NAME already running..."
else
nohup $CMD > $LOG_FILE 2>&1 &
echo $! > $PID_FILE
echo "$NAME listener is started..."
fi
}

function stopnotification {
kill `cat /var/run/$NAME.pid`
rm -f $PID_FILE
echo "$NAME listener stopped."
}
case $1 in
start) startnotification;;
stop)  stopnotification;;
restart)
stopnotification
startnotification;;
*)
echo "usage: $NAME {start|stop}" ;;
esac
exit 0
```

When I execute the command

```
/usr/local/bin/rtl_fm -o 4 -A lut -s 22050 -f 254.2355M - | /usr/local/bin/multimon-ng -t raw -a POCSAG1200 -f alpha /dev/stdin |& /home/me/import.rb
```

In my bash cmd it works fine.
But when I do a `sdr.sh start` I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/rtl_fm: invalid option -- 'a'
```

As you can see, the `-a` is a parameter of `multimon-ng` and not of `rtl_fm`.
It seems, that this pipe is not interpreted as pipe.

Comment: "Obverse" or "observe"? I know the word "obverse" exists. In cases like this my English is not that good to be 100% sure that you made a typo.

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about observing, it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect there is some additional info being returned by that `ps ... grep` line in your `startnotification()` function. To debug this further I would run the script with some debugging turned on first.

```
function startnotification {
set -x
VAR=`ps -ef | grep "$CMD" | grep -v grep | wc -l`
if [ $VAR -gt 0 ]; then
echo "$NAME already running..."
else
nohup $CMD > $LOG_FILE 2>&1 &
echo $! > $PID_FILE
echo "$NAME listener is started..."
fi
set +x
}
```

Using `set -x` will enable verbose messaging, and `set +x` will disable it. This should shed additional light on where your script is failing.